# How to make a edittext view fill the parent element in android

Tags: android, xml

I have two edittext views. One of them has only one line, its the title. But the other one should fill the linearlayout to the end, but it doesn't.
I updated the code so this is my whole xml for this app. I hope someone can find what's wrong. The part that i want to form like this is the part inside the LinearLayout named addView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#ffffff">

<LinearLayout  
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/addbuttonstyle"
        android:layout_weight="20"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/titleView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/titleview"
        android:layout_weight="60"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/orderButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/orderbuttonstyle"
        android:layout_weight="20"/>

</LinearLayout>  

<FrameLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> 
    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/addView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/textBoxTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="note title"
            android:singleLine="true"

            />
         <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/textBoxContent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:hint="content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@+id/backgroundLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found what was wrong.
I needed to set layout_height (of the textBoxContent view) to 0dp and layout_weight (of the textBoxContent view) to 1.

Answer (score 1):

I changed `textBoxTitle`'s height to `wrap_content` and I see this:

[image: Screen Shot]

Is this what you were hoping for? Also if you want `content` to appear in the upper-left corner use this attribute:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:gravity="top"
    />
```

Comment: It didn't work. I updated my code so now you can see my whole xml.
The LinearLayout tha is inside the FramLayout and on top of the LinearLayout addView slides to the left when i click a button. The addView layout should be an add note form.

Answer (score 0):

The first view should have android:layout_width="wrap_content"